# What can I do to install kdl?

Tags: ros, package, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I'm traying to install kdl but I'm having some problems.
I followed this site [link](http://wiki.ros.org/kdl) and when I tried to write "rosdep install kdl" I had the following error:

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource kdl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/jade/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/user/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/jade/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/jade/stacks
```

I read that this command installs  some system dependencies for source packages but not the package. Indeed if I type "roscd kdl" it turns out that it doesn't exist. How can I do to install kdl?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235909/what-can-i-do-to-install-kdl?/) by [mushroom](https://answers.ros.org/users/27053/mushroom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-02**:
Do you *need* to build it from source?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-02**:
Also: the wiki page you refer to shows that the last version of that package was for Groovy. You are running Jade. They may be / are probably not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki page you link points to [orocos_kdl](http://wiki.ros.org/orocos_kdl) for ROS versions *hydro onward*. If you don't need to build from source, a `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-orocos-kdl` should work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0